# Using scoped services (ie DbContext) from two scopes without service locator

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, service-locator

I need to write some service with method that needs to perform two units of work, where second one will be preformed even if first failed and was rolled back.
Creating and rolling back transaction is not enough, because DbContext still remembers changes from first unit of work.
Therefore I need two DbContexts.
Because I use other services to perform the work itself, I need to get the DbContext to them and i want it to be injected, not manually created or obtained via service locator.

Usual approach is to inject IServiceScopeFactory, create scope and from it resolve services involved in the work (DbContext to manage transaction and some service to do the work using this DbContext). What I don't like about this, is that nowhere in signature of the containing service or it's methods is information that those services are needed, and that my service knows about IServiceScopeFactory therefore knows at least something about used DI framework.

I'd like solution that allows my services to know as little as possible about DI framwork (it is allowed to know that conceptually scopes exist, but should not depend on any class/interface from DI framework).

example of what I don't want:

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext { 
}

public class SomeService
{
    private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    public SomeService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using(var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            var dao = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DaoService>();
            using (var tx = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    dao.FirstWork();
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                } 
            }
        }

        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            var dao = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DaoService>();
            using (var tx = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    dao.SecondWork();
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DaoService
{
    private MyDbContext _db;

    public DaoService(MyDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void FirstWork(){}
    public void SecondWork() { }
}

public class Test
{
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        new SomeService(/*now i need to prepare DI and register services, but i don't know which servicies I need*/null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make your question more concrete by including some code examples? Your question is very abstract, which makes it hard to supply you with useful advice.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, EF Core already does it. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work that tracks all changes and persists all of them when `SaveChanges` is called. That's why it's *meant* to be scoped, without extra transactions. It doesn't even open a connection until it has to either load new data or you explicitly call `SaveChanges` to commit the changes

Comment: The phrase `DbContext still remembers changes from first unit of work.` is simply wrong. If you reuse the DbContext, you have a critical bug. A DbContext instance *is* the Unit-of-Work.

Comment: As for DI, `AddDbContext` already registers DbContexts as scoped. In ASP.NET Core, a controller's endpoint's scope is the request so you get transaction-per-request semantics right out of the box. The DbContext instance injected in your controller or action only serves the request

Comment: If `SomeService` was scoped itself, you wouldn't need any extra code. Just add your DbContext-derived class as a constructor dependency ,or better yet, make `DaoService` scoped and add *that* as a dependency.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My requirements are that in one request, two units of work should be done. Therefore making SomeService scoped does not help.
I admit that for this example, explicit transaction is superfluous, but in actual code, there are stored procedures involved and multiple save changes to accomodate them.

he phrase DbContext ... is explanation of that critical bug and why it's inapropriate solution.

Comment: What do you thing "two units of work" means? What's the *actual* requirement and why can't you do that by calling `SaveChanges` twice? If the second UoW fails, should the first be rolled back? If so, you don't have two UoWs, you're asking for only one. If the first shouldn't be rolled back, two `SaveChanges` should work. `SaveChanges` is *not* a surrogate for executing stored procedures though

Comment: `there are stored procedures involved and multiple save changes to accomodate them.` I repeat. Again. And Again. DbContext isn't a database connection, EF Core isn't a data access library, that's what ADO.NET does. ORM means Object-to-Relational-Mapper. It's meant to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and stored procedures. If you try to use it as a SqlConnection, you're misusing it

Answer (score 0):

Inject some kind of scope factory with result type of IDisposable (or marker interface, but I dislike those) and service factory method for each dependency i need resoved from the scope, that resolve service from the scope object.

This way I can use DI framework or manualy create needed object and when manualy creating them, I cannot miss a dependency, because I know about it, because i must provide the service factory.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
}

public delegate IDisposable CreateScope();
public delegate T CreateScopedService<T>(IDisposable scope);

public class SomeService
{
    private CreateScope _scopeFactory;
    private CreateScopedService<MyDbContext> _dbContextFactory;
    private CreateScopedService<DaoService> _daoFactory;

    public SomeService(CreateScope scopeFactory, CreateScopedService<MyDbContext> dbContextFactory, CreateScopedService<DaoService> daoFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
        _daoFactory = daoFactory;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory())
        {
            var dbContext = _dbContextFactory(scope);
            var dao = _daoFactory(scope);
            using (var tx = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    dao.FirstWork();
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }

        using (var scope = _scopeFactory())
        {
            var dbContext = _dbContextFactory(scope);
            var dao = _daoFactory(scope);
            using (var tx = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    dao.SecondWork();
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DaoService
{
    private MyDbContext _db;

    public DaoService(MyDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void FirstWork() { }
    public void SecondWork() { }
}

public class Test
{
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        new SomeService(() =>
        {
            MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();
            return new TestScope
            {
                DaoService = new DaoService(ctx),
                DbContext = ctx
            };
        }, 
        d => d is TestScope scope ? scope.DbContext : null!,
        d => d is TestScope scope ? scope.DaoService : null!
        );
    }
}

public class TestScope : IDisposable
{
    public required MyDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    public required DaoService DaoService { get; set; }

    public IDisposable CreateScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is fundamentally broken. The DbContext is the IDisposable type you talk about. It's not a database connection, it's your Unit-of-Work *instance* and need no extra transactions. It tracks *all* pending changes during its lifetime and persists *all* of them in a single internal transaction when you call `SaveChanges`. To discard the changes, you dispose the DbContext

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbcontextfactory-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

From pure technical perspective (without getting into details WHY, it actually seems that you having a bit more [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here) there are at least two approaches you can try.

1. Use [`DbContext` factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) approach.

   Basically you swap the `services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(...)` registration and go with `services.AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(...)` one and then resolve it in the service (actually you can still resolve `AppDbContext` too when needed) and create contexts on the fly:

   ```
   // IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext> _contextFactory
   ...
   using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext()) // you should dispose the factory created contexts
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. You can tackle the *"because DbContext still remembers changes from first unit of work"* issue via EF Core change tracker-specific APIs i.e.:

   ```
   // after first transaction
   context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
   ```